How does System Settings signal the Dock to reload changed settings?
I am changing a Dock setting (e.g. autohide) from a script using defaults:
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide -bool true

but I don't how to trigger the running Dock process to reload its settings. I know I can force restart it by sending SIGTERM:
killall Dock

but this is pretty disruptive (e.g. any minimized windows are restored and so on).
When I change the setting manually in the System Settings app, the Dock behavior changes instantly so there must be a way. Is there a different signal I need to send?

It might be an XPC message vs a signal.
